# pivoting a column in awk

Tags: awk, pivot

I have the following text file

`cat file.txt`

```
name        value
ID1         a;b;c
ID2         d
ID3         e;f
```

I would like to pivot these.

**DESIRED OUTPUT**

```
name        value
ID1         a
ID1         b
ID1         c
ID2         d
ID3         e
ID3         f
```

I thought

txt.awk

```
BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" }

NR>1 {
     a=$1 split($2,a,";"); next
}

NR>1 {
     a=$1 for (i in a)
          print a, a[i]
     printf "\n"
}
```

but this fails to initiate the arrays. Is there an alternative?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***EDIT:*** As per Ed sir's suggestion adding following solution.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  OFS="\t\t"
}
FNR==1{
  print
  next
}
{
  num=split($2,array,/;/)
  for(i=1;i<=num;i++){
    print $1,array[i]
  }
}
'  Input_file
```

Could you please try following.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  OFS="\t\t"
}
FNR==1{
  print
  next
}
{
  num=split($2,array,";")
  for(i=1;i<=num;i++){
    print $1,array[i]
  }
  delete array
}
'  Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
name        value
ID1             a
ID1             b
ID1             c
ID2             d
ID3             e
ID3             f
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above code.

```
awk '                          ##Starting awk program from here.
BEGIN{                         ##Starting BEGIN section from here.
  OFS="\t\t"                   ##Setting OFS as 2 times TAB for all lines here.
}                              ##Closing BEGIN section of this code here.
FNR==1{                        ##Checking condition if line is first line then do following.
  print                        ##Printing current line here.
  next                         ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}                              ##Closing FNR==1 condition BLOCK of this program here.
{
  num=split($2,array,";")      ##Splitting 2nd field into an array named array whose delimiter is semi-colon and total number of elements will save into num variable.
  for(i=1;i<=num;i++){         ##Starting a for loop from i=1 to till value of num variable here.
    print $1,array[i]          ##Printing first field and value of array with index of variable i here.
  }
  delete array                 ##Deleting array here.
}
'  Input_file                  ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: You don't need `delete array` after processing since `split()`-ing the array at the start of processing clears it out first. In fact before the `delete` command was introduced to the awk language `split("",array)` **was** the way to "delete" an array. The 3rd arg to split() is a regexp btw, not a string, so that should be `/;/`, not `";"`.

Comment: @EdMorton, Sure thanks  a TON sir for correcting here, I have added solution now sir, cheers :)